# Masstransit execute events sequentially

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit, saga, event-driven

I'm using event-driven architecture, I'm using RabbitMq for queueing, and masstransit for a saga pattern.
I have events which I want these events execute sequentially, for example when EventOne finished executing, the saga should fire EventTwo automatically, I only call the request client for the first event, and it continues firing the events sequentially till last event.
Could any one help me with this ?
Thank you all for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute activities in order, based upon an initial event, I'd suggest using a routing slip. MassTransit [Courier](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/courier/) supports the execution and compensation of activities without the need of a central orchestrator.